# Access violation using a C++ function from a DLL

Tags: c++, opengl, c++11, dll

I have a game engine written in C++ which I'm porting to Windows (from Mac). It uses C++11 and OpenGL, and for all intents and purposes, it runs!

I'm using a DLL for my game engine which is linked implicitly to the game `.exe` at runtime. The problem is, when I try to use a utility class from the DLL, `FileSystem`, to find a resource file (a texture, but I don't think it's important), I get this error:

`First-chance exception at 0x00007FF9CF988830 (PocoFoundation64.dll) in TestEquinox.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000136A4FF000.`

The problem comes when I call this method of my `FileSystem` class from the DLL (it's designed to take a filename/partial path and it looks in various places to find the full path):

```
Poco::Path FileSystem::Get(const std::string &filename) {
std::vector<Poco::Path> paths = {
        filename,
        ResourceFolder() / filename //<<<<< ERROR HERE
    };

    for (const Poco::Path &path : paths) {
        try {
            if (Poco::File(path).exists()) {
                return path;
            }
        } catch (...) { }
    }

    Logger("FileSystem", std::cerr) << "Could not find file '" << filename << "'!";
    return {};
}
```

Visual Studio shows the error as being at the call of `ResourceFolder()`, another method from the same class, also in the DLL. This appears so:

```
Poco::Path FileSystem::ResourceFolder() {
    Poco::Path userData;

    //--SNIP-- (other OS's #ifdef'd here)
    // GAME->StartupPath is a std::string containing the exe's parent folder
    userData = (Poco::Path(GAME->StartupPath).parent() / "Resources").makeDirectory();
    //--SNIP-- (and here)

    try {
        if (!Poco::File(userData).exists()) {
            Poco::File(userData).createDirectories();
        }
    } catch (...) {}

    return userData;
}
```

From the looks of it, it's to do with `Poco`'s data types not being instantiated properly? I've built it from source with all the same compiler settings (64-bit, multi-byte character set, VS2013), so I don't see how it could be a name mangling/data layout issue.

One more thing to note - I copied the entire `FileSystem` class from the DLL to a class local to my game project, called `FileSystem2`. Calling `FileSystem2::Get` with the same parameters worked correctly and without crashing, despite being the same code.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction?!

Comment: `64-bit, multi-byte character set, VS2013`  You need to check the runtime library settings also.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on that? Where in Visual Studio would one set that for the runtime library?

Comment: `Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library`  These must match up with all the modules you're compiling.

Comment: These are both Multi-threaded debug DLL for my engine and the game itself, but I'll check Poco, thanks!

Comment: Okay, you may want to re-write your comment as an answer so I can tick it! I was linking with PocoFoundation.lib, which is Multi-threaded DLL, rather than PocoFoundationd.lib, which Multi-threaded *debug* DLL!

Comment: ok.  I have added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually errors like this stem from using incompatible runtime libraries that your module uses.  Please check the following for all of your modules in the Visual Studio properties:

`Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library`.

The runtime setting (Multithread DLL, Multithread Debug DLL, etc.) must match up with all the modules you're compiling.  If they do not match, choose one runtime, and rebuild all of your modules using that runtime.

Comment: Yup, this was it. Was linking against the release version of one of the dependencies (PocoFoundation.dll vs. PocoFoundationd.dll) while building for Debug. This meant the runtime setting was incompatible as you say!